# Two forms Two Models in one view CakePHP 3

Tags: forms, view, controller, entity, cakephp-3.0

I have my project with Cake 3, I want create two forms in the same view, I will explain my problem.

I have the first form to create users, but I want to create more address, so I have  BelongsToMany for create and associated many locations. So, I have to create this location when I create users, then I need to use `LocationController>add();` in `UsersController>add();`- but how to do this? 
In my `UsersController` i have :

```
use App\Controller\LocationController;
```

But when I try to create new patch entity for location, there was no error.

```
$location = $this->Locations->newEntity();
```

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT - 2** 
In my view,  I try

```
echo $this->Form->input('customers.0._locations.name');
echo $this->Form->input('customers.0._locations.number');
```

But in my CustomersController
I find it tedious code, if i have many input

```
$data = [
'title' => 'First Post',
'tags' => [
    ['tag' => 'CakePHP'],
    ['tag' => 'Framework']
 ]
];
```

Comment: Multiple forms, trying to access other controllers, etc, that's all just really bad practice. You should start by reading about [**associations**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html), [**how to save**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-associations) them, and how to [**create appropriate forms**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-inputs-for-associated-data) for them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I do not understand very well the documentation, so i edit my first message.